# JavaScript Function Return Some Value

Tags: function, javascript

I have defined a JavaScript function

```
function a()

 {
    var data = 'some data';
    $.getJSON(networkController,data,function(r) {
            $.each(r, function(a)
            {
                alert(r[a].networkAccessToken);
        });
   });
}
```

It works fine but When I do it as:

```
 function a()

 {
    var data = 'some data';
    $.getJSON(networkController,data,function(r) {
            $.each(r, function(a)
            {
                return r[a].networkAccessToken;
        });
  });
 }
var c = a();
alert(c);
```

Alert is undefined.....

Comment: check again .....It is right syntax
other wise give total code

Comment: How are you fetching the value from the database? Are you sure the value is parsed correctly?

Comment: can we see the code that sets the value for b or what is it..

Comment: if function a() is callback function of ajax call then if you call it directly it will not have value b unless called asynchronously by ajax engine.

Comment: This example looks really clear and work fine. (check out: http://jsfiddle.net/D8DFu/) I think, you've got an other problem... show your full code

Comment: `function a()

{
  var data = 'some data';
  $.getJSON(networkController,data,function(r) {
    $.each(r, function(a)
    {
     return r[a].networkAccessToken;
    });
 });
}`

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman, pls add the above code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to realise that your AJAX call is *non-blocking*. This means that it returns *before* a response is received from the server. (The first "A" stands for "Asynchronous"!)

The most common way to handle this is to use a [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_science%29):

```
 function a(callback) {
    var data = 'some data';
    $.getJSON(networkController,data,function(r) {
        $.each(r, function(a) {
            callback(r[a].networkAccessToken);
        });
    });
 }

 a(function(c) {
   alert(c);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, Asynchronous JavaScript and XML is Asynchronous. When you call `$.getJSON` it sends an HTTP request and registers a function to run when the data gets back. It then gets one with running the existing function while it waits for that.

You are effectively trying to do something like:

```
function a() {
    $('button').click(function () { return 1; });
}
foo = a(); // Would you expect this to be `1` and not `undefined`?
```

Second, `each` calls a function for each value. The function you pass to `each` is called by `each` not `getJSON` or `a`. Its return value only determines if the loop should be continued or not.

You need to do whatever you want to do **in the function you pass to `each`**. You can't pass data back up the calling chain. What you want to pass back to no longer exists.

Comment: Is that not ok `return $.each(r, function(){
    return r[a].networkAccessToken;           
  });`